# Typo3: Add and substitute custom marker in PageRenderer

Tags: php, typo3, markers

I'm using Typo3 version 10.4.6 with the following config:

```
config.pageRendererTemplateFile = path/to/CustomPageRendererTemplate.html
```

In this custom page renderer file I have added a new custom marker `###MYMARKER###` inside the head section.

I need to substitute this custom marker with a specific string.

In general I need to insert a script in the head section of my page right after the opening head tag. A custom marker seems to be the only possibility render my script at the desired position.

I do not want to use the disableAllHeaderCode option!

My approach so far:

```php
$templateService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(MarkerBasedTemplateService::class);
$templateService->substituteMarker(
    'fileadmin/sitedesign/Resources/Private/Templates/PageRendererTemplate.html',
    '###MYMARKER###',
    '<link rel="test" content="Test content">'
);
```

Unfortunately the marker is not substituted.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `<script>` part can be easily done with TypoScript:

```
page.includeJS.myscript = /path/to/my/script.js
```

Also, CSS files can be added with TypoScript.
More see here: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#includejs-array

Also, you can change the `<head>` tag to directly add a tag directly after it, see: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Setup/Page/Index.html#headtag

Comment: Yes, but how can I control the position where this script is going to be added? I need it right after the head tag.

Comment: I've edited the answer with an option to edit the <head> tag, so you can add your HTML part directly after it.

Comment: Thanks, that workaround helps but it seems not to be the perfect solution.